# Group features of TF-IDF vector in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification, tfidfvectorizer

I'm using scikit-learn to train a text classification model based on TF-IDF feature vector by following piece of code:

```
model = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()
feature_vector_train = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(X)
model.fit(self.feature_vector_train, Y)
```

I need to rank the extracted features in decreasing order of their TF-IDF weight and group them into two non-overlapped sets of features and finally train two different classification model. How can I group the main feature vector into an odd-ranked set and an even-ranked set?

Comment: Are you trying to group the features by their TF-IDF weight (i.e. before they are sent to the model), the weight the model gives each feature, or the combined weight (TF-IDF weight * model weight)?

Comment: @acattle I need to group them before they are sent to the model.

Comment: So you wanted to rank the features according to their TF-IDF weight and then break them into two separate feature matrices for two separate classifiers?

Comment: @acattle Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your `TfidfVectorizer` is an `n x m` matrix `n` is the number of documents and `m` is the number of unique words. Thus, each column in `feature_vector_train` corresponds to a specific word from your dataset. Adapting a solution from [this tutorial](https://buhrmann.github.io/tfidf-analysis.html) should allow you to extract the highest and lowest weighted words:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
feature_vector_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

total_tfidf_weights = feature_vector_train.sum(axis=0) #this assumes you only want a straight sum of each feature's weight across all documents
#alternatively, you could use vectorizer.transform(feature_names) to get the values of each feature in isolation

#sort the feature names and the tfidf weights together by zipping them
sorted_names_weights = sorted(zip(feature_names, total_tfidf_Weights), key = lambda x: x[1]), reversed=True) #the key argument tells sorted according to column 1. reversed means sort from largest to smallest
#unzip the names and weights
sorted_features_names, sorted_total_tfidf_weights = zip(*sorted_names_weights)
```

From this point you should be able to separate the features as you'd like. Once you have them into two groups, `group1` and `group2`, you can separate them into two matrices like this:

```
#create a feature_name to column index mapping
column_mapping = dict((name, i) for i, name, in enumerate(feature_names))

#get the submatrices
group1_column_indexes = [column_mapping[feat] for feat in group1]
group1_feature_vector_train  = feature_vector_train[:,group1_column_indexes] #all rows, but only group1 columns

group2_column_indexes = [column_mapping[feat] for feat in group2]
group2_feature_vector_train  = feature_vector_train[:,group2_column_indexes]
```